# Problem with showing base64 encoded image

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, base64

I'm getting Base64 string of an Image from an android app

app converts image => bitmap
bitmap => byteArray
scale that byteArray by 100
then create base64 string of that image

when I use that encodedd image string to show on web using "img/jpg;base64"+encodedstring it shows partial image as show in image below.

[image: Improper image]

Comment: I do not understand why or how you "scale that byteArray by 100". That is not how images are scaled or cropped

Comment: @Barns - a bitmap could be scaled using a byteArray

Comment: Two steps seems to be missing though ... `scaledByteArray => scaledBitmap` and `scaledBitmap => jpegImage`

Comment: @JaromandaX :: I meant that you cannot scale an image that way. But you can crop them which is apparently what the OP got...I do not know what the original image looked like.